# Kendo UI: Unable to save record details on Editing/Updating a record in Grid

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

**Scenario :**
I am binding records in a JSON file to a grid using Kendo UI MVVM. I've set the editable property to Popup, hence on editing a record, the popup opens however on modifying data and updating, the record does not get updated. Hence, to close the popup I click the Cancel button.

After some research I came across the Save function. Which updates the record in the grid.

**Question :** 
How shall I define the save function in an MVVM scenario?? generally the save function is defined on the grid as follows:

```
$("#myGridView").kendoGrid({
    //...
    save:function(){
        this.refresh
    }
)};
```

The above works well in a non MVVM standard. 
How am I suppose to do the same thing MVVM way?

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    dataSource:new kendo.data.DataSource({
        //...
    }),
    save:function(){
        //how to implement the same refresh functionality?
    }
});
```

For now I have attached the `save` event on the grid `events: { save: save }`. The `save` function gets called, but when I click "Update" in popup nothing happens. In firebug it says `this.refresh` is not a function.

Where am I going wrong??

Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` is not the same here...
If you want to refresh the grid, I guess you have to write this :

```
save : function() {
    $("#myGridView").data("kendoGrid").refresh();
}
```

Comment: Hi Samuel, Thank you so much for the feedback!! :) That worked... Thanks!! So I need to use the above syntax whenever I need to perform any action on the grid rite?

Comment: @Hardik yes, this is just that for your first piece of code, your context was your grid, so you can use directly `this`...